# Send data to php script via httpclient c#

Tags: c#, php

I have a php script that has variables like this:$devicetoken and $eventmessage. In c# using a http client how can I send up that information. I am not a strong php developer. Thanks for any help

Comment: You're not strong with PHP or c# ? Post your PHP code. Do you want to send it from aspx or application ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is passing them in the URL, e.g. the C# client opens an URL like http://www.example.com?devicetoken=123&eventmessage=Hello%20world!

More information in PHP's manual http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php